# Open a program in a Java frame

Tags: java, jframe

I want to open a program in a new frame in Java, for example: I want to open the Notepad.exe with Java, that's easy, but it opens a Notepad.exe window, I need to make the Notepad.exe open inside a new jFrame, is that even possible?

What I really need is to control the focus of this new window, I'm trying to do this by opening the program inside a jFrame, instead of letting it's open in a new Window.

Any help/sugestion would be very helpful.

Comment: It is not directly possible. What scenario/usage do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Take a loook at JDIC to see if it fits your needs.  I don't think that would be possible though, I think JDIC works only for ActiveX docs and such.